# How to drag and drop body using onTouchListener and still being in PhysicsWorld? AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-engine

I want to drag and drop body with its sprite using touch. I do know how to drag and drop sprite,  but when I try to move body it... doesn't work, body stays still. What's more, sometimes when I touch body the whole app crashes :x
Can anyone tell me how to drag and drop physic body that collides with other bodies during movement of finger? I've been searching for 3 days and im depressed :[

I've created 3 similar bodies. One is dynamic(simulation of ball bouncing like in Hockey Game), two of them are kinematic(Will be moveable by players). I will show you declaration of the body I want to move.
I don't know if any code is needed to show you but I implemented some interfaces found in really bad tutorial. :s

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener, IOnAreaTouchListener
```

Declaration:

```
//Declaration:
         final Sprite face = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2+200f, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                return true;
            }
        };
        final FixtureDef MyFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.2f,0.4f,0.6f);

        this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
        face.setScale(3);
```

Body:

```
final Body facebody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(
        this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.KinematicBody,
        CIRCLE_FIXTURE_DEF);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face,
        facebody, true, true));
    facebody.setUserData("player1");
```

Methods:

I tried MouseJoint

```
  public MouseJoint createMouseJoint(IAreaShape face, float x, float y) {
final Body boxBody = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager()
    .findBodyByShape(face);

Vector2 v = boxBody.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(x / 32, y / 32));

MouseJointDef mjd = new MouseJointDef();
// mjd.bodyA = ballbody;
mjd.bodyB = boxBody;
mjd.dampingRatio = 0.2f;
mjd.frequencyHz = 30;
mjd.maxForce = (float) (200.0f * boxBody.getMass());
mjd.collideConnected = true;
mjd.target.set(v);
return (MouseJoint) this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(mjd);
}
```

nor onAreaTouched?

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final ITouchArea pTouchArea, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
        final IAreaShape face = (IAreaShape) pTouchArea;
        if(this.mMouseJointActive == null) {
            //this.mEngine.vibrate(100);
            this.mMouseJointActive = this.createMouseJoint(face, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

here just guessing

```
        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                Debug.d("here!");
return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Question about class:

If I declare class player inside MainActivity:

```
 class Player {
final Body facebody;
final Sprite face = new Sprite(MainActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH / 2+200f,240, MainActivity.mFaceTextureRegion ,getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
            final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

        switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
        case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Here 'body' refers to the Body object associated with
            // this sprite
            facebody.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(),
                pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), facebody.getAngle());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
        }
    };

    Player(Body f) {
        facebody = f;
    }

    }
```

Everything is perfect but,it yells that `player.face` can't be declared in
OnCreateScene in this declaration:

```
final Player player= new Player( PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(   this.mPhysicsWorld, player.face, BodyType.KinematicBody,CIRCLE_FIXTURE_DEF));
```

How shall I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok finally I found good solution 
take it to onCreateScene:

```
        final AnimatedSprite face;
    final Body body;

    final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);


        face = new AnimatedSprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2+200, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        face.setScale(3);
        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
    face.animate(new long[]{200,200}, 0, 1, true);
    face.setUserData(body);
    body.setUserData("player");
    this.mScene.registerTouchArea(face);
    this.mScene.attachChild(face);
```

on AreaTouched:

```
    @Override
public boolean onAreaTouched( final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final ITouchArea pTouchArea,final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {

        final AnimatedSprite face = (AnimatedSprite) pTouchArea;
        final Body faceBody = (Body)face.getUserData();
        faceBody.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, faceBody.getAngle());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I didn't make class player, I took  it to onCreateScene. And important part of drag and drop is to devide X and Y by  `PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating the problem. Take it step by step:

1. Create your sprite, and a body for that sprite. By the sound of your problem I would also try making the body dynamic as opposed to kinematic, but it is your call.
2. On the declaration of your sprite, override onAreaTouched. Set it up as follows:

   ```
   sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mTextureRegion, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
       @Override
       public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

           switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()){
               case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   //Here 'body' refers to the Body object associated with this sprite
                   body.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(),
                                     pSceneTouchEvent.getY(),
                                     body.getAngle());
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
           return true;
       }
   };
   ```

The most important part of this is that you are **moving the body, not the sprite**. This should in turn translate the sprite.

After that, depending on how you want your face to behave, play with whether you want your object to be kinematic or dynamic.

Comment: Hey! I am trying to test it. And just one question about access to body inside onAreaTouched - is everything inside onSceneCreate? It doesn't see body inside onAreaTouched:(

Comment: It depends how you have declared body as a variable. When I design my objects I do something fancy where I make a class, for example Ball, which has the variables Sprite and Body. That way I can just call body by going this.body (or possibly super.body, not sure). 

Just make sure it is visible though. If your really stuck, just make a global variable inside the whole class. Its messy, but it works.

Comment: longshorts, I finally did it your way but when I touch my body/sprite it disappears, do u know what could go wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but use logcat to find out. You may have the transform coordinates wrong (something I commonly do). Just Log.d("Body", "Coords: " + pSceneTouchEvent.getX() + " " + pSceneTouchEvent.getY());

Comment: You need to divide pSceneTouchEvent.getX()/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT for transform from metters to pixels